# WPF SVG image binding using a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, binding, ivalueconverter

I would like to change my image source from:

```
<Image Source="{svg:SvgImage image.svg}"/>
```

To something that use binding on an enum property instead:

**XAML:**

```
<Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Resources>    

<Image Source="{svg:SvgImage Binding MyEnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
public enum MyEnum 
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}

public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var myValue = (MyEnum)(value);
        switch (myValue)
        {
            case MyEnum.Value1:
                return "image1.svg";
            case MyEnum.Value2:
                return "image2.svg";
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and I suspect that is has something to do with the `svg:SvgImage` and `Binding MyEnumProperty` being combined in the same statement.

I get the following errors:

```
The member "Converter" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

And

```
The property 'Converter' was not found in type 'SvgImageExtension'.
```

**Question:**
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
{svg:SvgImage Binding MyEnumProperty ...}
```

is not valid XAML, and because SvgImage is a markup extension, you can't bind its properties.

You may however use DataTriggers in an Image Style instead of a Binding with a Converter:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyEnumProperty}" Value="Value1">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg:SvgImage image1.svg}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyEnumProperty}" Value="Value2">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg:SvgImage image2.svg}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the data triggers dynamic? In case I have another property `MyOtherEnumProperty` and I would like to use the same triggers for it, could I change the data triggers to handle both of the properties?